# GCC - toggle each of the instruction set manually without toggling many at once using march?

Tags: gcc

Say I have a code that is planned to run on a computer with SSE2, and I want the compiler to generate code for SSE2. I can take a look at GCC's [march list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) and see that Pentium-m has SSE2 and MMX, so I can do `march=pentium-m`. How can I toggle each of the instruction set, using something like `-march=sse3 -march=mmx`?

Comment: It's further down in the list, `-msse` etc

Comment: -msse allows you to call compiler's SSE intrinsics manually. If you don't, nothing changes.